# How to update row using Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a model:

```
class Announcements(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    text = db.Column(db.Text(), nullable=False)
    category = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    subcategory = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    offer_type = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    url = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=True)
    status = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Announcement %r>' % self.name
```

And public function:

```
def update(id):
   // UPDATE HERE
```

How to update note by passed `id` in function `update()` using Flask-SQLAlchemy?

I dont see any examples of updating rows in [documentation](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First get the item you need.

```
item = Announcements.query.get(id)
```

Then you edit that item directly:

```
item.name = "Newname"
```

Then you commit the session:

```
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: How to clone row by `id`?

Comment: it update whole row, or only update name ?

Comment: @Dolphin it updates the name